# SQL constraint violation on foreign key ORA-00001 unique constraint

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys

Here is the error message:

```
Error starting at line : 207 in command -
    INSERT ALL
        INTO employees
            VALUES
                  ( 777, 'Pereira', 'Daniele',
                    'x1400', 'name@email.com', '4',
                    1088, 'Head Cashier' )
        INTO employees
            VALUES
                 ( 18161884, 'Samuel', 'Rowbotham',
                   'x6400', 'drsamuelrowbotham@parallax.co.uk', '4',
                   1088, 'Cashier' )
    SELECT * FROM employees WHERE reportsto = 1088
Error report -
ORA-00001: unique constraint (DBS211_202A27.SYS_C001065272) violated
```

This happens even if I disable the foreign key constraint:

CODE:

```
ALTER TABLE employees
DISABLE CONSTRAINT EMP_RTEMP_FK;
INSERT ALL
    INTO employees
        VALUES
              ( 777, 'Pereira', 'Daniele',
                'x1400', 'name@email.com', '4',
                1088, 'Head Cashier' )
    INTO employees
        VALUES
             ( 18161884, 'Samuel', 'Rowbotham',
               'x6400', 'drsamuelrowbotham@parallax.co.uk', '4',
               1088, 'Cashier' )
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE reportsto = 1088;
ALTER TABLE employees
ENABLE CONSTRAINT EMP_RTEMP_FK;



Table EMPLOYEES altered.
Error starting at line : 207 in command -
    INSERT ALL
        INTO employees
            VALUES
                  ( 777, 'Pereira', 'Daniele',
                    'x1400', 'name@email.com', '4',
                    1088, 'Head Cashier' )
        INTO employees
            VALUES
                 ( 18161884, 'Samuel', 'Rowbotham',
                   'x6400', 'drsamuelrowbotham@parallax.co.uk', '4',
                   1088, 'Cashier' )
    SELECT * FROM employees WHERE reportsto = 1088
Error report -
ORA-00001: unique constraint (DBS211_202A27.SYS_C001065272) violated
Table EMPLOYEES altered.
```

Constraint info:
`EMP_RTEMP_FK   Foreign_Key     DBS211_202A27   EMPLOYEES   SYS_C001065272  NO ACTION   ENABLED NOT DEFERRABLE  VALIDATED   USER NAME           20-05-26`

Comment: You disabled the constraint named `EMP_RTEMP_FK` while the error said that the constraint with name `SYS_C001065272` was violated. Anyway, disabling constrainnts is not a good way because this error wii appear again if you enable constraints back. Just dro the constraint completely or do not insert ducplicated data int the table.

Comment: Ok, I've been asked to insert both of these values into the table in one statement, and there are other 'employees' listed with the same foreign key in 'reportsto' (1088).  The only thing I could think of was disabling the constraint.  When I create the two employees in separate statements, they both get created with the correct data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT ALL
    INTO employees
        VALUES
              ( 777, 'Pereira', 'Daniele',
                'x1400', 'name@email.com', '4',
                1088, 'Head Cashier' )
    INTO employees
        VALUES
             ( 18161884, 'Samuel', 'Rowbotham',
               'x6400', 'drsamuelrowbotham@parallax.co.uk', '4',
               1800, 'Cashier' )
```

It was a case of RTFQ/working long hours and going blurry.  Second value was 1800, not both at 1088.  This ended up working.